# Animate a SVG on hover, yet maintain img tag benefits?

Tags: html, svg

I need to load an svg and animate certain parts of it on hover.

After some research, it appears you can only do this by using an inline svg.

However, you would then lose the benefits of an external file referenced with `img`, caching, google image search, and accessibility via an alt tag.

My question is, is there a way to maintain these aspects of using an `img` tag, but still maintain the ability to animate an svg on hover using css?

Comment: Not as far as I know. (Not sure, if it would work, if you used a "minimal" `svg` element inline, that uses `use` to refer part of an _external_ svg, that would be something worth testing perhaps.)

Comment: img, image, background-image etc are never interactive, so no. You could use <object> or <iframe> though.